# How to work with maps in different views

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, controller, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show different maps in different views but charging 1 on 1 map view, switch to another map not load, there is no mistake to launch the browser so I could not decide because I can not keep showing other maps. I'm doing as follows:

```
$scope.cargarUbicacion = function () {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          latitud_actual = position.coords.latitude; 
          longitud_actual = position.coords.longitude;
          console.log(latitud_actual);
          console.log(longitud_actual);
          var mapOptions = {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitud_actual, longitud_actual),
              zoom: 15,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              scrollwheel: false
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa_ubicacion"), mapOptions);
          $scope.setMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(latitud_actual, longitud_actual), 'Yo', '');
      });
    }
  } 
  $scope.setMarker = function(map, position, title, content) {
  var marker;
  var markerOptions = {
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: title,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
  };

  marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
  markers.push(marker); // add marker to array

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
      // close window if not undefined
      if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
          infoWindow.close();
      }
      // create new window
      var infoWindowOptions = {
          content: content
      };
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

I am using this code in multiple controllers, my idea is encapsulated and can occupy the same code 1 time in several views. Whenever I change the id map to avoid that problem, thinking that this was the cause that did not load the map.

Any idea how to do what I need or that is failing to load maps?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by " but charging 1 on 1 map view, switch to another map not load, there is no mistake to launch the browser".. Please explain your question in a simple way so that its self explanatory.

Comment: @AniV I refer to occupy maps in different views, but the problem is that loading the map in one all right. I see another view and does not charge any map and no error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personnaly do the following :

The code taht you want to reuse put it into a global variable such as :
Then into your control, you can extend it with this mapExtend

```js
    global.MapExtend = function($scope, $rootScope, leafletData) {

// ... all your functions to reuse
      };

// In your main controler, extend it with your map capabilities with angular.extend
angular.extend(myCtrl, new MapExtend($scope, $rootScope, leafletData));
```